# The Prismic fulltext predicate keeps giving me errors about unexpected fields when I Use it to try to query

Tags: vue.js, prismic.io, jamstack

I am trying to query with the Prismic predicate.fulltext using Vuejs
this is the first time am using the predicate but the documentation about what the fulltext predicate needs seems to be confusing. Here is my code.

```
async searchByQuery(query) {
    const fullTextResult = await this.$prismic.client.get({
      predicates: this.$prismic.predicate.not("articles.article_title", query),
    });
    console.log(fullTextResult);
  },
```

where articles is my custom type and article_title is a field in my custom type.
That is what I understood from the documentation on how to do it but then I get an unexpected error

[image: Prismic Fulltext Predicate error]

I would like a clarification on why this does not work and what the documentation really mean.
Am Using Vue3 by the way and that means am using the updated prismicio/client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close!

Using Vue 3, you're looking at something like that:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async searchByQuery(query) {
      const fullTextResult = await this.$prismic.client.get({
        predicates:
          this.$prismic.predicate.fulltext(
            "my.articles.article_title",
            query
          )
      });

      console.log(fullTextResult);
    }
  }
};
```

Basically, you need to prefix `articles.article_title` with `my.` to indicate it's a field on one of your document type, and change the predicate you're using to `precidate.fulltext` instead of `predicate.not` (assuming you want to run a fulltext search)

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Voila it works. Thanks for your answer lucie. in the place of the not predicate I have actually been using the fulltext predicate. I switched it to not just to test if it will work which it didn't but forgot to switch back to ask the question.